# MVC Linq Date Compare to DateTime.Now.Day not correct

Tags: datetime

I am trying to get today record from below code. But it return yesterday record unless I add one day into linq. But DateTime.Now.Day is correctly shown. What went wrong.

```
        var data = from s in db.SalesItems
                   where (
                        s.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year &&
                        s.Date.Month == DateTime.Now.Month &&
                        s.Date.Day == DateTime.Now.Day+1
                        )
                   select s;
        ViewBag.StatusMessage = data.FirstOrDefault().Date + " " + DateTime.Now.Day;
```

StatusMessage = "20/05/2014 12:07:57 PM 20"

Comment: Sounds like a UTC vs local time issue.  What is the timezone offset for each of the dates?

Comment: That may be the thing, because I connect the DB in smarterasp.net, and running the code local. But the db record is 20/05/2014 12:07:57 PM